# Multiple applications can share the same ACL tables?

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.2

Currently I have to share my database with many CakePHP applications and the tables are prefixed to identify each application respectively.

So, can many applications share the same ACL tables?

Or, I could change the default names of the tables ACL and add the prefix of each application, eg. app_aros, app_acos, app_aros_acos?

```
/* beforeFilter() @ AppController */
$this->Acl->Aro->useTable = 'app_aros';
$this->Acl->Aco->useTable = 'app_acos';
```

This code worked but I haven't found a way to change the tablename of the model Permission...

Suggestions? What could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have change this line in app/Config/core.php in all of your apps

```
Configure::write('Acl.database', 'default');
```

to:

```
Configure::write('Acl.database', 'your_acl_connection');
```

And also add connection in app/Config/database.php

example:

```
public $your_acl_connection = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
```

Simply you will have one DB for managing all yours app ACLs.
In this DB you create all ACL tables.